# How to enforce a specific Spring Security version dependency in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

How do you ensure Spring Security >3.2.1 is used in accordance with this [documented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/431), [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2046)?:

```
class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] 
cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I've tried [upgrading it](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) in my `POM.xml` with no luck (**Intellij** complains the version doesn't exist):

[image]

My local repository path in Intellij Maven Settings is correct. I hover over its complaint and select "Update Maven Indices". It tries to update my local repository, returning only that the dependencies do not exist.

So, how else can I ensure **GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class** is found?

Comment: For starters, post your POM, but that should do it. You might need to specifically depend on the actual package in question, not just indirectly.

Comment: By using the [`spring-boot-starter-security`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) dependency that has all the right ones. Also there is no Spring security release 4.0.2, the latest is 4.0.1. But you really should be using the starters instead of trying to figure out working dependency versions yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you make this an answer? This is the actual solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the current answer to this question can be found here:

#### Gradle

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html#getting-gradle-boot

e.g. for Spring Security version 5.7.0-SNAPSHOT specify property

```
ext['spring-security.version']='5.7.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

in your Gradle file

#### Maven

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/getting-spring-security.html#getting-maven-boot

e.g. for Spring Security version 5.7.0-SNAPSHOT specify property

```
<properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <spring-security.version>5.7.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-security.version>
</properties>
```

Also remember that if you're going to try out new builds that might not exist in public Maven repositories, you might have to add Spring's own repositories, for example `https://repo.spring.io/snapshot`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using older spring boot starter but you want latest security you could do something like this

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot use the different Spring Boot Starter projects to get the appropriate dependencies. For Spring Security that implies to adding the [`spring-boot-starter-security`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) dependency to get all necessary Spring Security dependencies.

Using the starters will save you from hunting down the correct dependencies and dependency versions, you will get a working set of dependencies this way.